# Putting a JSON string into a database in C

Tags: c, json, function, pointers, berkeley-db

Below is my code:

```
#include <json/json.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <db.h>

#define  DATABASE "access.db"


/*printing the value corresponding to boolean, double, integer and strings*/
void print_json_value(json_object *jobj){
  enum json_type type;
  printf("type: ",type);
  type = json_object_get_type(jobj); /*Getting the type of the json object*/
  switch (type) {
    case json_type_boolean: printf("json_type_boolean\n");
                         printf("value: %s\n", json_object_get_boolean(jobj)? "true": "false");
                         break;
    case json_type_double: printf("json_type_double\n");
                        printf("          value: %lf\n", json_object_get_double(jobj));
                         break;
    case json_type_int: printf("json_type_int\n");
                        printf("          value: %d\n", json_object_get_int(jobj));
                         break;
    case json_type_string: printf("json_type_string\n");
                         printf("          value: %s\n", json_object_get_string(jobj));
                         break;
  }

}


/*Parsing the json object*/
void json_parse(json_object * jobj) {
  enum json_type type;
  json_object_object_foreach(jobj, key, val) { /*Passing through every array element*/
    printf("type: ",type);
    type = json_object_get_type(val);
    switch (type) {
      case json_type_boolean:
      case json_type_double:
      case json_type_int:
      case json_type_string: print_json_value(val);
                            db_json(&val);
                           break;
      case json_type_object: printf("json_type_object\n");
                           jobj = json_object_object_get(jobj, key);
                           json_parse(jobj);
                           break;
      case json_type_array: printf("type: json_type_array, ");
                          json_parse_array(jobj, key);
                          break;
    }
  }
} 

int db_json(char *val) {

typedef struct {

char data1[500];

} pearson_record;

pearson_record s;


int i =0;
 DB *dbp;
    DBT key, data;
    int ret, t_ret;
    int recno;



    if ((ret = db_create(&dbp, NULL, 0)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "db_create: %s\n", db_strerror(ret));
        exit (1);
    }

    // if ((ret = dbp->set_flags(dbp, DB_RECNUM)) != 0) {
        // fprintf(stderr, "db_create: %s\n", db_strerror(ret));
        // exit (1);
    // }

    if ((ret = dbp->open(dbp,
        NULL, DATABASE, NULL, DB_BTREE, DB_CREATE, 0664)) != 0) {
        dbp->err(dbp, ret, "%s", DATABASE);
        goto err;
    }

    strncpy(s.data1, val, strlen(val)+1);

    //printf("chk %\n",jvalue);

    recno = 10;

    memset(&key, 0, sizeof(key));
    memset(&data, 0, sizeof(data));
    //memset(&s, 0, sizeof(struct pearson_record));
    key.data = &recno;
    key.size = sizeof(recno);
    data.data = &s;
    data.size = sizeof(s);


     if ((ret = dbp->put(dbp, NULL, &key,&data,0)) == 0)
    printf("db: %d: key stored.\n", *(int *)key.data);
    else
    {
        dbp->err(dbp, ret, "DB->put");
        goto err;
    }

    pearson_record *ppr;
         if ((ret = dbp->get(dbp, NULL, &key, &data, 0)) == 0) {

    ppr = (pearson_record *) data.data;

    printf("db: %d: key retrieved: data was %s %d\n",
            *(int *)key.data, ppr->data1, data.size);
    }
    else {
        dbp->err(dbp, ret, "DB->get");
        goto err;
    }

    err:    if ((t_ret = dbp->close(dbp, 0)) != 0 && ret == 0)
        ret = t_ret; 

        exit(ret);
    }

int main() {

  char * string = "{\"Extracurricular\" : \"5,6,7,41,40,22,9,12,91,97\"}";
  printf("JSON string: %s\n", string);
  json_object * jobj = json_tokener_parse(string);
  json_parse(jobj);
}
```

When I am compiling the code i see the below warning:

try.c:81:8: warning: implicit declaration of function âdb_jsonâ

my output is: JSON string: {"Extracurricular" : "5,6,7,41,40,22,9,12,91,97"}
type: type: json_type_string
          value: 5,6,7,41,40,22,9,12,91,97
db: 10: key stored.
db: 10: key retrieved: data was p4È@4È¸4È 500

Basically i want to pass the value of my JSON string into a Berkeley DB database. I am not able to find whether there is a problem in passing the value to my function or is there something else. I am so sure I am making some small problem in pointers and functions. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To remove the warning declare `int db_json(char *val);` at the top of the program after includes.

Comment: @Banther: i did that but now i get these errors:try.c:82:8: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
try.c: At top level:
try.c:95:26: error: parameter 1 (âvalâ) has incomplete type

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that the `db_json` function accepts a `char*` as the parameter, but the call to it appears to be passing the address of a pointer to a `json_object`.  I'm not familiar with the functions, but it may be that you should be passing `json_object_get_string(jobj)` as the parameter to `db_json` since that appears to produce a character string of the JSON representation of the data.  Note that this is only a guess from the brief look at the code; I am not familiar with the types involved.